# Seeking Reverse Geocoding API?

Tags: geocoding, api, reverse-geocoding

I am working in a company where our team requirement is to do reverse geocoding lookups. Below is our requirement.

To give you more background, the 3 geolocation-related needs I have are as follows:

1. Lat/Long lookup: returning country, city, state, region, postal code
2. Address lookup: returning lat/long
3. Postal Code lookup: returning country, city, state, region, lat/long (I assume the lat/long of the postal code’s centroid is what is usually provided)

Which provider can I look into which will fulfill my above needs? I am looking for something which is used worldwide and are more reliable in terms of accuracy and coverage.

Comment: Postcode (alone) is going to be marginal at best, because they are not unique worldwide. For example, 1234 is a valid postcode at least Australia and the Philippines.

Answer (score 4):

I made good experience with [nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/).

Try this (College Park in Toronto)

[lat long lookup](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=43.659722&lon=-79.383795&zoom=18&addressdetails=1)
[address lookup](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=420%20yonge%20street,%20Toronto&format=xml&polygon=1&addressdetails=1)

More examples can be found here [examples](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE%3aNominatim).
It is in German but the examples are self declarative.

I guess the premium product is googles map API. Therefore I mentioned just something which might be an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a service, there is [PickPoint](https://pickpoint.io). It engages nominatim and OSM for geocoding.